# HTML/CSS structure to provide future design changes and skinning

Tags: html, css, user-controls, scaffolding, boilerplate

My current project requires building out a framework of components that will be re-used in the future on separately branded websites. These components are rolled up into ASP.NET User Controls (`*.ascx`). The same component will be on multiple branded sites, the only difference between them is the content and CSS. I need to structure the HTML in such a way to provide as much future flexibility for design tweaks only via CSS. Here's an example.

Say I'm creating a basic callout component to promote something. This would suffice for semantic and simple HTML:

```
<div class="callout">
  <h3>Headline</h3>
  <p>lorem ipsum...</p>
  <a href="#">Read more</a
</div>
```

However, depending on future design changes, there may not be enough HTML elements there to write CSS to match the design. Perhaps I need to be overly verbose and overload for future CSS skinning, something like this:

```
<div class="callout-outer">
  <div class="callout-inner">
    <div class="callout-top">
      <h3>Headline</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="callout-body">
      <p>lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="callout-bottom">
      <a href="#">Read more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Holy divitis batman! But really... the second structure would provide TONS of future CSS skinning flexibility for design changes, but semantically its garbage.

My questions:

- Are there any frameworks on boilerplates out there that already have a structure like this (I don't think Twitter Bootstrap would provide this much flexibility)
- Is this completely a terrible idea? (subjective, I know)

Comment: "the second structure would provide TONS of future CSS skinning flexibility for design changes, but semantically its garbage". It's not at all. In HTML5, `<div>`s have no meaning, so they're the perfect element to use for speculative styling hooks. Anything trying to interpret the page semantically will ignore them. The only thing I would say is that your root element might be better as a `<section>`, and your `<h3>` as an `<h1>`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a terrible idea - it's a good one and lots of people end up with HTML that looks like that:

My initial thought would be to design your site to use the [JQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) styling, that kind of forces you to think about the second example you gave, because things need to be animated or structured to support the concept of re-skinning based on CSS files.

I would however think carefully about the naming conventions of the DIV's, outer and inner are actually quite sensible :)

- The JQuery UI website also gives designers a nice way to change the look and feel of the website without making the CSS themselves (and still make it work afterwards).